# How can I make DataTable as Enumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have  table named Pinfo what I want to do is to fetch records from db using Linq query and return it.But I couldnt  do it .This is what I have so far.How can I make this work

```
List<ProductInfo> getList()
{
    List<ProductInfo> pi = new List<ProductInfo>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Project;User Id=sa;Password=1"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from PInfo", con))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var query = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        select new
                        {
                            id = c.Field<int>("Id"),
                            name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
                            price = c.Field<decimal>("Price")

                        };
            adp.Fill(query);
        }
    }

    return pi;
}
```

Comment: i think you forgot to run actual query before iterate over results

Comment: The table is empty. You cannot use ADO.NET as if it was Linq-To-SQL. You have to use `adp.Fill(dt)` first. Then you can use `Linq-To-DataTable`(`Linq-To-Objects`) to query the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

return  (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
         select new ProductInfo
                {
                     id=c.Field<int>("Id"),
                     name=c.Field<string>("Name"),
                     price=c.Field<decimal>("Price")

                 }).ToList();
```

- You shouldn't create anonymous types if you want to return a list of `ProductInfos`
- You don't need the `SqlDataAdapter`, just use `Load` method of DataTable.